# LLC tag has at least 3 different uses

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

The rarely used [llc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/llc) tag (30 questions in 9 years) has no description and at least 3 different meanings:

- The LLVM Static Compiler
- The Logical Link Control header in a network packet
- Last Level Cache of a CPU

Half of the questions also have the [llvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/llvm) tag.

Should this tag be split into multiple appropriate new tags?  Should it be abandoned?  Or is this tag too infrequent to spend time on?

Comment: I'm surprised that it isn't used for questions about American companies.

Comment: We wi [llc] orrect this.

Comment: All it would take is 30 sma [llc] hanges to split them into 3 tags.

Comment: At 30 questions, simply retagging them seems the way to go?

Comment: @the4kman The Brits have LLC businesses too, and it was the first thing I thought of.

Comment: "Limited liability company"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've added a description for the llc tag, stating that it is part of the LLVM toolset.

I've removed the llc tag from questions that do not pertain to other things (cpu caches and network packets).  There didn't seem to be enough of a need to create new tags for either use.

Comment: You need to be checking this tag frequently. There was one more asked this year. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53199824/revisions